# Loading other models within controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to experiment and do my first steps with Laravel 5 implementing a basic help desk app, whose main models are Ticket and Message.

I first defined the endpoint for the addition of a new message in an existing ticket with this route:

```
Route::post('tickets', 'TicketsController@store');
```

And the store() method within TicketsController:

```
   /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $messageTxt = $request->get('message'); 
        $ticket = Ticket::findOrFail($request->get('ticket_id'));
        $message = new Message();
        $message->text = $messageTxt;
        $ticket->messages()->save($message);
        return Redirect::action('TicketsController@show', $request->get('ticket_id'));
    }
```

Note that both models have a one to many relationship defined through the messages() method in this case. This was working without any problem. But I then realized this resource method would be more appropriate to create a brand new ticket, not a ticket message.

So when someone sends the form to create a new ticket message, this is the route I defined instead:

```
Route::post('messages', 'MessagesController@store');
```

Next I moved all the code above within TicketsController::store() to MessagesController::store(), but then I got this error:

> FatalErrorException in MessagesController.php line 40: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Ticket' not found

Line 40 corresponds to the request for the ticket with the ticket id. It looks like it has something to do with the Ticket model not being loaded here because it doesn't belong in this controller by convention, and it perfectly worked within TicketsController. I'm not of this sure though.

What should I do then to be able to use the Ticket model within the MessagesController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens a lot due to `namespacing` added in Laravel 5+.

You have a few options to remedy this. First, a `use` statement:

```
use App\Ticket;
```

Including this in your class declaration for `TicketsController` will allows `Ticket::findOrFail()` or any other `Ticket::` function to be called without issue.

As an added note, check the namespace in yout `Ticket.php` file. By default, a model's namespace should be:

```
namespace App;
```

Alternatively, if you only want say a single use in a different controller, you can specify the namespace before the function call. For example:

```
$ticket = \App\Ticket::where("id", "=", $ticketId)->first();
```

The issue is that with namespacing, php is trying to find a `Ticket` class in `App\Http\Controllers`, which (logically) there shouldn't be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've done what you said, but it also throws the error with Message and even with Redirect. Why is this happening here and it didn't in the other controller?

Comment: Now I see, I have to do it with Message as well, just like I have in TicketsController.

Comment: Haha, sorry for the late response, but I'm glad you got it working. If you ever get a `Class Not Found` with an odd Namespace (like `app/Http/Controllers` for a model), check that you're doing one of the above; adding the `use` statement at the top or including the correct Namespace on the actual usage line.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can import the model class at the top of your Controller like so:

`use App\Ticket;`

You can do this for all your other models too, e.g `use App\Message`.

Your other option is to just reference the correct namespace when calling it, like so; `\App\Ticket::where()`.